# Is there a way to force Open Refine to extract all history changes into JSON

Tags: openrefine

I was using Open Refine for a couple of days and noticed that I am allowed only to extract the last operations, probably only the ones made in the last execution of the project. The previous operations are in grey and won't let me select them. Is there any way to get the JSON associated with that operations?

[image: Open Refine]

Comment: This is clearly a bug: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1990

Comment: This was a bug, now fixed https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/pull/2026